# Why are we allowed to use を particle with na-adjectives?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-を, na-adjectives

Can someone explain the usage of a *na*-adjective with the を particle?

I cannot understand why we can say

> ほうれん草を嫌いな人もいる。

because I'd thought that it had to be a が or の particle instead of an を.

Also, why can we say

> きみがなぜジャズを嫌いか私にはわからない。

Shouldn't it be きみがなぜジャズが嫌いか私にはわからない?

(Source: [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=%E3%82%92%E5%AB%8C%E3%81%84&from=und&to=und))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this is that generally speaking, **you can't use を with na-adjectives**. This is not standard usage for most na-adjectives. Additionally, although Google searches also attest this kind usage for 嫌い (at least), the Tanaka Corpus is [known to have errors](http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/Tanaka_Corpus#Compilation), so it's best to be careful.

[A google search for "を嫌い"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%92%E5%AB%8C%E3%81%84%22) shows that the *large* majority of results, the を is clearly being used with some other verb, e.g. Xを嫌いになった。 However, in some, it is used in the way you noted, as in the following example:

> - Yを嫌いなワケについて語られていた。

This を is clearly attached to 嫌い, *not* 語る. So, back to your question: **why?** As [@Axioplase's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/why-are-we-allowed-to-use-particle-with-na-adjectives/1845#1845) suggests, this is primarily seen with 好き and 嫌い, and so I argue that the reason you see を with these "na-adjectives" is that they are derived from the *verbs* 好く and 嫌う, respectively. They are both transitive verbs, and as such, accept objects readily. As such, using を with them in certain circumstances is not odd at all, though it may seem so when considered primarily as na-adjectives rather than verbs. I hypothesize that this usage is common with verb-derived na-adjectives, but *not* other na-adjectives.

Comment: thanks alot =D btw besides 嫌い and 好き can you think of 1 or 2 other  verb-derived na-adjectives ?

Comment: @Pacerier Nope! Sorry. I'll let you know if I do, though.

Comment: ok i'll be waiting =P

Comment: In strict grammar it'd be wrong though. If you want to be Japanese grammar nazi, you can insist on usage of either `Yを嫌うワケ` or `Yが嫌いなワケ`

Comment: 〜を嫌いになる is really interesting!  But なる is actually intransitive, so I'm not sure we can explain the accusative case assignment that way, either.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a nuance (which I don't understand very well) and that in some situations, having を (at least for 好き and 嫌い) instead of の or が helps reading the sentence which may have already too many other の's and が's and be too ambiguous.