# What is going on grammatically with "Xを嫌いになる"?

Tags: transitivity

I've observed native speakers use this construction (similarly with 好き).

Does this mean that なる can be used transitively and take a direct object in some cases? Is this related to the idea that something becomes liked or disliked as an involuntary action (and thus "嫌いにする" wouldn't fit)?

Answer (score 9):

It's not なる but 嫌い that is "taking the direct object" (?) in this sentence. AFAIK なる itself is always intransitive.

嫌い is a common na-adjective which means "dislike" in the form of X**が**嫌いだ. See: [Using 嫌い and 嫌う](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29029/5010) and [私は猫が好き and 猫は私が好き](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17857/5010)

"na-adjective + になる" is a common way to say "become ～".

> - 元気になる become healthy, recover
> - きれいになる become beautiful

So X**が**嫌いになる means "to come to dislike X (over time)".

Moreover, X**を**嫌いになる means almost the same thing as X**が**嫌いになる. This phenomenon has been asked about several times on this site, so please read the followings:

- [Why are we allowed to use を particle with na-adjectives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1841/5010)
- [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010)
- [Why is を used in this situation? 私は先生がネコを好きだと思います](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4210/5010)

Comment: Thanks. I searched around and read the linked questions, one of which referenced "Xを嫌いになった", but didn't find anything conclusive. Can we consider "嫌い" in this case to be more of a nominalized form of "嫌う" than the typical na-adjective?

Comment: You mean "nominalized" in [this sense](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010)? Hmm, 嫌い as in ネコ嫌【ぎら】い and 好き as in [魚好【ず】き](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36645/5010) are almost like nouns to me, but as for Xを嫌いになる or Xが嫌いです, I kind of "feel" these 嫌い are adjectives... This is definitely nonstandard, but some people confuse it with an i-adjective and even say [好きくなる/好きくない](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1290818587).

Comment: That's what I was getting at. I guess I'm searching for a transitive verb in the sentence so that I can understand the use of を in terms of a transitive verb and a direct object. Maybe it's a mistake to try and analyze it in this way, and I should just accept this as a special case.